# Chainlink VRF callback gas limit set too low

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I'm writing an integration test of my NFT practice project using Chainlink VRF v2 subscription method, but keep getting callback gas limit set too low error

My contract is deployed on `sepolia testnet` with following settings

- gas lane: `0x474e34a077df58807dbe9c96d3c009b23b3c6d0cce433e59bbf5b34f823bc56c`
- gas limit: `500000`
- vrfcoordinator address: `0x8103B0A8A00be2DDC778e6e7eaa21791Cd364625`

and the account I use for testing also have enough sepoliaETH

You can find the full implementation of my practice project at https://github.com/ambersun1234/nft and the deployed contract

- [0x6933D3e699B948ff8cadec1091f25B6C8718E307](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x6933D3e699B948ff8cadec1091f25B6C8718E307)(with `500000` gas limit)
- [0x08dc70E094C9A7720914D1f2b81b4351686554cA](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x08dc70e094c9a7720914d1f2b81b4351686554ca)(with `2500000` gas limit)

> The subscription of Chainlink VRF that I created currently have 18 Link
> The contract will spend 0.2 Link per call

The file for integration test is

- [nft/contracts/IpfsNFT.sol](https://github.com/ambersun1234/nft/blob/master/contracts/IpfsNFT.sol)
- [nft/test/integrationTest/ipfsNFT.spec.ts](https://github.com/ambersun1234/nft/blob/master/test/integrationTest/ipfsNFT.spec.ts)

Step to reproduce

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ambersun1234/nft
$ cd nft
$ yarn install
$ yarn hardhat test --network sepolia
```

I've checked all of the settings correct or not(gas lane, subscription id ... etc.)
and even change the gas limit up to `2500000` but all in vain

To check if Chainlink works on other network, I also checked `goerli testnet` of my another project and it works

Comment: @sabertooth It turn's out that I have an error in my code(shown as below), also make sure that all the configuration of chainlink is correct(i.e. gas limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the issue is simple
make sure you put `_safeMint` before `_setTokenURI`
otherwise you'll encounter with this weird issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the callbackGasLimit? Your operations could be using ether gas (gwei) (not just LINK).  The error is saying that insufficient gas is the problem.

For the sepolia VRF2 coordinator, the max gas limit specified is 2,500,000
(see https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2/subscription/supported-networks/#sepolia-testnet)

Comment: Yes I've increased the gas limit up to 2500000 but still not working

Comment: Could you please link to where you're setting your gaslimit? it would be helpful to point to the exact line where the failure is happening and a screenshot of the error message

Comment: The gas limit is set in [helper-hardhat.config.ts](https://github.com/ambersun1234/nft/blob/master/helper-hardhat.config.ts#L46)
and I've create another contract with `2500000` gas limit, as shown is the origin post